# Derivative of integration variable

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I'm coming from a physics background and I'm working with some equations where the following expression occours

$ \frac{d}{dx} \int f(y(x)) \, d(y(x))$

If the dependence of $x$ would only be in the integrand $f$ I would have no problem. But that the integration variable depends on $x$ confuses me. I have been looking around the net and think about it for a couple of days now. Can somebody give me a hint how to solve this. References are welcome, because at the moment I simply don't know what keywords, theorems etc. to look for.

Best regards

Comment: How about expressing the derivative operator $d/dx$ in the form of $d/dy$? I imagine one could apply the chain rule here.

Answer (score 1):

Chain rule could be applied.

\begin{align}
  \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} \int f(y(x))\ \mathrm d(y(x))
&   = \left(\frac{\mathrm d(y(x))}{\mathrm dx}\right)^{-1}
      \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d(\color{blue}{y(x)})}
      \int f(\color{blue}{y(x)})\ \mathrm d(\color{blue}{y(x)}) \\
&   = \left(\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}\right)^{-1} f(y(x))
\end{align}